# Do not underline text inside 'div' element wrapped by 'a' element

Tags: html, css

I have a following template and I want to not underline text inside a `div` when a link is hovered:

```
<a href="#">
   <div class="card">
      <h2>Title</h2>
   </div>
</a>
```

I tried the rule below but text is still underlined on hover:

```
a:hover .card {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: can u share more of your css ? maybe you are overwriting stuff ? try also to use !important

Comment: @דולבדובלון, thanks. It helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the underline is happening on the anchor tag, you have to target that tag only:

```css
a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <div class="card">
      <h2>Title</h2>
   </div>
</a>
```

Edit: to only use the underline when a `.card` div is inside the a tag:

```css
a,
a:hover .card {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a .card {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: although for legacy issues you may not want to use div's inside of an anchor tag

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in this case `text-decoration: none;` is applied to all links. Is it possible to apply it to my scenario only (when a link contains .card element)?